# Refresh DownloadUrl on google map v3 and remove old markers

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

Hi I had a script and a xml file with 10.000 markers in it. I use markercluster to display the markers, but in order to fill the mobile browsers requierement I must begin the map at a certain zoom level (not to display to many markers). So I want to dynamically load the markers when the user change the zoom or viewport.

Here is my script. I thing I can't get the lat and lng of the LatLngBounds of the current viewport :

```js
var customIcons = {
      chambrehote: {
        icon: '/wp-content/themes/codium-extend/images/chambre.png',
        shadow: '/wp-content/themes/codium-extend/images/icon-shadow.png'
      }
    };

    function initialize() {
      var cluster = [];
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng('45.7676067','4.8351733'),
        scrollwheel: false,
        zoom: 12,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });

    var mcOptions = {gridSize: 100, styles: [
          {
            textColor: 'black',
            height: 80,
            url: "/wp-content/themes/codium-extend/images/cluster-m1.png",
            width: 90
          },
          {
            textColor: 'black',
            height: 80,
            url: "/wp-content/themes/codium-extend/images/cluster-m2.png",
            width: 90
          },
          {
            textColor: 'black',
            height: 80,
            url: "/wp-content/themes/codium-extend/images/cluster-m3.png",
            width: 90
          }
    ]};      

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    var swPoint = bounds.getSouthWest();
    var nePoint = bounds.getNorthEast();

    var swLat = swPoint.lat();
    var swLng = swPoint.lng();
    var neLat = nePoint.lat();
    var neLng = nePoint.lng();

        downloadUrl("/wp-content/themes/codium-extend/search/search_chambres.php?&type=chambrehote&codgeo=<?php echo $CODGEO ; ?>&radius=200&lat1="+swLat+"&lng1="+swLng+"&lat2="+neLat+"&lng2="+neLng+"", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("ville");
          var slug = markers[i].getAttribute("slug");
          var stars = markers[i].getAttribute("stars");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> " + "<br/>" + "" + "><a href=" + "/chambre-d-hote/" + slug + "/>lien vers la fiche</a>";

          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          //var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
          //bounds.extend(point);
          //map.fitBounds(bounds);
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {                                                                      infowindow.setContent(markers[i].getAttribute("name"));
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, i));
          cluster.push(marker);

        }
      var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map,cluster,mcOptions);


      });

     }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    function changePosition() {
      var position = document.getElementById('position').value;
      adUnit.setPosition(google.maps.ControlPosition[position]);
    }
```

First point :
I think I couldn't get the value of swLat, swLng... for passing them to downloadUrl

And second point I certainly miss a listener somewhere but don't know where !
Thanks for your inputs

---- EDIT ----

Right now I can load dynamically the data when the idle is changed, but (there is a but) now each change a new marker is add even if it's already on the map. Is there a way to clean all the markers when the idle change before loading the new ones?

```js
var cluster = [];
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
         zoom: 12,
         center: new google.maps.LatLng('45.7676067','4.8351733'),
         mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });

       var mcOptions = {gridSize: 100, styles: [
          {
            textColor: 'black',
            height: 80,
            url: "/wp-content/themes/codium-extend/images/cluster-m1.png",
            width: 90
          },
          {
            textColor: 'black',
            height: 80,
            url: "/wp-content/themes/codium-extend/images/cluster-m2.png",
            width: 90
          },
          {
            textColor: 'black',
            height: 80,
            url: "/wp-content/themes/codium-extend/images/cluster-m3.png",
            width: 90
          }
    ]};      
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

       google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'idle', function() {

        var bounds = map.getBounds();
        var swPoint = bounds.getSouthWest();
        var nePoint = bounds.getNorthEast();
        var swLat = swPoint.lat();
        var swLng = swPoint.lng();
        var neLat = nePoint.lat();
        var neLng = nePoint.lng();
          // alert(swLng);

          downloadUrl("/wp-content/themes/codium-extend/search/search_chambres.php?lat=45.7676067&lng=4.8351733&type=chambrehote&codgeo=<?php echo $CODGEO ; ?>&radius=2000&lat1="+swLat+"&lng1="+swLng+"&lat2="+neLat+"&lng2="+neLng+"", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("ville");
          var slug = markers[i].getAttribute("slug");
          var stars = markers[i].getAttribute("stars");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> " + "<br/>" + "" + "><a href=" + "/chambre-d-hote/" + slug + "/>lien vers la fiche</a>";

          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          //var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon,
            shadow: icon.shadow
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
          //bounds.extend(point);
          //map.fitBounds(bounds);
          google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow.setContent(markers[i].getAttribute("name"));
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                        }
                    })(marker, i));
          cluster.push(marker);

        }
      var mc = new MarkerClusterer(map,cluster,mcOptions);


      });  


      });


    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    function changeFormat() {
      var format = document.getElementById('format').value;
      adUnit.setFormat(google.maps.adsense.AdFormat[format]);
    }

    function changePosition() {
      var position = document.getElementById('position').value;
      adUnit.setPosition(google.maps.ControlPosition[position]);
    }
```

Comment: Why do you say you can't get the viewport?  `google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'bounds_changed', function() { var bounds = map.getBounds(); alert(bounds); });` should work.

Comment: Do you know why                                                          `var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 var swPoint = bounds.getSouthWest();
 var nePoint = bounds.getNorthEast();
 var swLat = swPoint.lat();
 var swLng = swPoint.lng();
 var neLat = nePoint.lat();
 var neLng = nePoint.lng();` doesn't work in this case? tx

Comment: The Google Maps Javascript API v3 is event driven.  If you don't wait for the map to be initialized (the first bounds_changed event), the bounds won't exist.  And the code you posted (which is hard to read in the comments, please update your question) creates an empty bounds object, don't you want the bounds of the "map"/viewport (`map.getBounds()`)?

Comment: I edit the question, your comment help me to refresh the data, but now for each move I add markers to the map even they already on it! So maybe I must clean the map after the move and before loading the new set?

Comment: If your query returns markers that are already there, don't add them again (use either an ID or the position of the marker to detect equivalence).  You can delete all the existing markers (call setMap(null) on them first, then add the new ones if you want from your request, but if the map is moving a lot that may cause undesirable side effects (like the markers "flickering", disappearing and reappearing).

Comment: Nice idea, and is it possible to delete the markers who are now outside the map (based on getBounds()) ?

Comment: Of course it is. [google.maps.LatLngBounds.contains](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLngBounds)